# Spring WebFlux/Reactive Mongo based application opens multiple connections to mongo db

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a simple web application with spring boot 2.x.x , Spring WebFlux for reactive apis and Reactive Mongo Repository. 
In the application I have a `@Tailable`query associated with a get API to infinitely observe changes saved in DB. And I have a post API to push data in the db.
But the application opens multiple connections to mongo randomly. Sometimes these connections are reused.

LOGS

```
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:342}] to localhost:27017
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:344}] to localhost:27017
```

And so on..
So I added a configuration class to restrict connections per host

```
  @Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.maxConnectionIdleTime}")
    private int  maxConnectionIdleTime;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.connectionsPerHost}")
    private int connectionsPerHost;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.minConnectionsPerHost}")
    private int minConnectionsPerHost;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.socketTimeout}")
    private int socketTimeout;


    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoOptions() {
        return MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .maxConnectionIdleTime(this.maxConnectionIdleTime)
                .connectionsPerHost(this.connectionsPerHost)
                .minConnectionsPerHost(this.minConnectionsPerHost)
                .socketTimeout(this.socketTimeout)
                .build();

    }
}
```

Now when I run the Get api (one that indefinitely observes databse), the application still opens multiple connections to DB, but closes few of them due to idle time out.

Logs :

```
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:345}] to localhost:27017
Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:345}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:348}] to localhost:27017
Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:348}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:351}] to localhost:27017
Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:351}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:9, serverValue:354}] to localhost:27017
```

**EDIT**

From further observation, it is opening a connection and then closing it after 60 secs if the connection is not being used. For example in logs below connections with local id 5 and 6 are being used to tail mongo events via apis and remaining connections are just idle connections that close after a minute.
**EDIT** changed the mongo configs to ->

```
 server:
    port: 8081
spring:
    data:
        mongodb:
            database: LocalMongo
            uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/LocalMongo?maxpoolsize=5
            maxConnectionIdleTime: 15000
            connectionsPerHost: 40
            minConnectionsPerHost: 1
            socketTimeout: 60000
```

Is this ok?

```
2019-12-10 21:45:32.862[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.p.test.Application     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Application in 3.489 seconds (JVM running for 4.87)
[2m2019-12-10 21:46:31.977[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:899}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
[2m2019-12-10 21:46:31.983[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:903}] to localhost:27017
[2m2019-12-10 21:47:28.917[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntLoopGroup-2-2][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:905}] to localhost:27017
[2m2019-12-10 21:47:31.122[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ntLoopGroup-2-3][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:906}] to localhost:27017
[2m2019-12-10 21:47:31.974[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:903}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
[2m2019-12-10 21:47:31.981[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:907}] to localhost:27017
[2m2019-12-10 21:48:31.974[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:907}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
[2m2019-12-10 21:48:31.983[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:910}] to localhost:27017
[2m2019-12-10 21:49:31.975[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:910}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
[2m2019-12-10 21:49:31.981[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:9, serverValue:913}] to localhost:27017
[2m2019-12-10 21:50:31.974[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m20092[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[imer-1-thread-1][0;39m [36morg.mongodb.driver.connection           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:9, serverValue:913}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
[2m
```

Is there a best practice around this?

**FURTHER EDITS**
As suggested in the comments, I used `uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/LocalMongo?maxpoolsize=5`
to set max pool size of 5. And mongo ensures maximum of 5 open connections as expected and the connection expires once the idle timeout is reached.
However, every time the connection is terminated, a new one opens up. Basically, it looks like it is ensuring atleast 5 connections are opened. Is there a concept I'm missing here?

LOGS:

```
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:2843}] to localhost:27017
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:2844}] to localhost:27017
: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:2846}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:00:17.316  INFO 10748 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-3] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:2848}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:00:20.436  INFO 10748 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-4] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:2849}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:00:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:2844}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:00:39.125  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:2851}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:01:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:2851}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:01:39.125  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:2854}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:02:39.123  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:8, serverValue:2854}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:02:39.123  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:9, serverValue:2856}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:03:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:9, serverValue:2856}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:03:39.125  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:2859}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:04:39.123  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:2859}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:04:39.125  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:11, serverValue:2862}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:05:39.122  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:11, serverValue:2862}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:05:39.125  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:12, serverValue:2865}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:06:39.123  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:12, serverValue:2865}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:06:39.126  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:13, serverValue:2868}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:07:39.123  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:13, serverValue:2868}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:07:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:14, serverValue:2870}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:08:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:14, serverValue:2870}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:08:39.128  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:15, serverValue:2873}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:09:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:15, serverValue:2873}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:09:39.125  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:16, serverValue:2876}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:10:39.123  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:16, serverValue:2876}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:10:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:17, serverValue:2879}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:11:39.122  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:17, serverValue:2879}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:11:39.129  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:18, serverValue:2882}] to localhost:27017
2019-12-13 13:12:39.123  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:18, serverValue:2882}] to localhost:27017 because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.
2019-12-13 13:12:39.124  INFO 10748 --- [imer-1-thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:19, serverValue:2885}] to localhost:27017
```

Please do let me know if additional information is needed. I'll edit this space here.

Comment: it seems that it's closing all previously opened connections, doesn't it?

Comment: not all... for example connectionId with local values 1,2,3 didn't close... Also what is the ideal number of connections per host for a production system?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by setting `maxConnectionIdleTime=1`, which you can see in logs as well: `...because it is past its maximum allowed idle time.`

Comment: But max connections per host is also 1, then how is it opening multiple connections?
I changed the configs as well before the 2nd set of logs.. I'll add them in the edited section

Comment: If you need to limit the count of connections per app, use connection pool settings instead. For example just change the connection string like this: `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017?maxIdleTimeMS=1500000&maxpoolsize=1`

Comment: @ChiragC Just in case it's something this simple - your configuration you've pasted there sets `minConnectionsPerHost` to 1, not `maxConnectionsPerHost`.

Comment: @VladK I set the max pool size to 5 using the parameter you suggested. Now, I  added some load on the application and it ended up opening max of 5 connections as expected. Once these connection becomes idle, connection is closed, which is also as expected.
But every time it closes one connection, it opens a new one, ensuring minimum of 5 connections. Basically, maxpoolsize=5 appears to be more of minimum number of connections to be open. Am I missing something here?

Comment: There is no concept like this, max pool defines upper limit only. Probably it is caused by MongoClientOptions somehow. I would suggest debugging Spring Mongo AutoConfigs, it is tricky sometimes... I ended up not exposing `MongoClientOptions ` at all and having all settings in the connection string, check the class `com.mongodb.ConnectionString` for property names and descriptions.